# javax.naming.NameNotFoundException EJB HelloWorld on WildFly

Tags: java, ejb, wildfly

I am a beginner in EJB 3.1 and trying to run my first Hello World program and getting the NameNotFoundException.

```
Exception in thread "main" javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: WFNAM00004: Name "global/HelloWorld/HelloWorldBean!api.HelloWorldRemote" is not found
at org.wildfly.naming.client.util.NamingUtils$1.lookupNative(NamingUtils.java:95)
at org.wildfly.naming.client.AbstractContext.lookup(AbstractContext.java:84)
at org.wildfly.naming.client.WildFlyRootContext.lookup(WildFlyRootContext.java:150)
at javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup(InitialContext.java:417)
at driver.HelloWorld.main(HelloWorld.java:27)
```

Here are my classes

Local Interface:

```
@Local
 public interface HelloWorldLocal {
public void getHello();
 }
```

Remote Interface:

```
@Remote
public interface HelloWorldRemote extends HelloWorldLocal {

 }
```

Bean Class:

```
@Stateless(name="HelloWroldBean")
public class HelloWorldBean implements HelloWorldLocal, HelloWorldRemote{

@Override
public void getHello() {
    System.out.println("Hello Cheppura");
}

  }
```

Client:

```
public class HelloWorld {

public static void main(String[] args) throws NamingException {
    final Hashtable<String, String> jndiProperties = new Hashtable<>();
    jndiProperties.put(Context.URL_PKG_PREFIXES, "org.jboss.ejb.client.naming");
    jndiProperties.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY,         
            "org.wildfly.naming.client.WildFlyInitialContextFactory");
    Context con = new InitialContext(jndiProperties);

    final String appName = "";
    final String moduleName = "HelloWorld";
    final String beanName = HelloWorldBean.class.getSimpleName();
    final String viewClassName = HelloWorldRemote.class.getName();

    Object ob = con.lookup("java:global" + appName + "/" + moduleName  + "/" + beanName + "!" + viewClassName);

    HelloWorldRemote hw = (HelloWorldRemote) PortableRemoteObject.narrow(ob, HelloWorldRemote.class);

    hw.getHello();
}
```

}

Can anyone please advice on this?
Thanks in advance

Comment: I've never used WildFly, but it looks like you're not actually registering the bean anywhere. `con.lookup` looks for registered beans, but there's nothing telling WildFly to create an instance of `HelloWorldBean`.

Comment: What is the reason to extend the Remote interface from the Local one?

Comment: You have a typo on your implementation in the Stateless anotation you wrote: HelloWroldBean. Please correct and try again. 

Comment: @Pulszar I guess it makes no sense in that case.

Comment: What is your deployment unit - JAR or EAR?

Comment: @AlexSergeenko Thanks for the reply, I inherited the remote because to write less code., I am using JAR as deployment Unit

Comment: @Bhargav Krishna Were there any warnings in the server log during the deployment process?

Comment: Have you checked this example? https://github.com/wildfly/quickstart/tree/master/ejb-remote

Answer (score 0):

You've violated the JEE specification, since there is no inheritance in EJB interfaces.

Your `Remote` interface extends the `Local` one but such approach goes against the specification. I think such EAR will never deployed correctly, regardless a runtime environment.

If you want to write a less code this way, then create a third interface with the `public void getHello();` method and extend it in both `Local` and `Remote` interfaces.

```
public interface Secondary {
    public void getHello();
}

@Remote
public interface HelloWorldRemote extends Secondary {
 }

@Local
 public interface HelloWorldLocal extends Secondary{
 }
```

Comment: Why is extending a violation?

Comment: @BrunoJCM Such approach will work perfectly on most application servers, but I think it intricates the code, making it messy. Also EJB 3.0 spec says: "The same business interface cannot be both a local and a remote business interface of the
bean.[4]"